# Scope of Local Variables in Shell Functions

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, variable, function

After reading [24.2. Local Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html), I thought that declaring a variable `var` with the keyword `local` meant that `var`'s value was only accessible within the block of code delimited by the curly braces of a function.

However, after running the following example, I found out that `var` can also be accessed, read and written from the functions invoked by that block of code -- i.e. even though `var` is declared `local` to `outerFunc`, `innerFunc` is still able to read it and alter its value.

<kbd>[**Run It Online**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMd1ptTmpoOWUyS3M)</kbd>

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function innerFunc() {
    var='new value'
    echo "innerFunc:                   [var:${var}]"
}

function outerFunc() {
    local var='initial value'

    echo "outerFunc: before innerFunc: [var:${var}]"
    innerFunc
    echo "outerFunc: after  innerFunc: [var:${var}]"
}

echo "global:    before outerFunc: [var:${var}]"
outerFunc
echo "global:    after  outerFunc: [var:${var}]"
```

Output:

```
global:    before outerFunc: [var:]               # as expected, `var` is not accessible outside of `outerFunc`
outerFunc: before innerFunc: [var:initial value]
innerFunc:                   [var:new value]      # `innerFunc` has access to `var` ??
outerFunc: after  innerFunc: [var:new value]      # the modification of `var` by `innerFunc` is visible to `outerFunc` ??
global:    after  outerFunc: [var:]
```

**Q: Is that a bug in my shell (bash 4.3.42, Ubuntu 16.04, 64bit) or is it the expected behavior ?**

**EDIT:** Solved. As noted by @MarkPlotnick, this is indeed the expected behavior.

Comment: It is the expected behavior

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks it's weird that on the last line of output the value of `var` is empty? `var` is set globally in `innerFunc`, so why doesn't it stick until the end of the script?

Comment: What about if `innerFunc` is called at the end (after the final `echo`)? It prints `innerFunc:                   [var:new value]`. It seems that this creates a new global `var` (as shown by one final additional `echo "global:    after  outerFunc: [var:${var}]"`).

Answer (score 52):

Shell variables have a [dynamic scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping). If a variable is declared as local to a function, that scope remains in effect until the function returns, **including during calls to other functions**!

This is in contrast to most programming languages which have [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope). Perl has both: [`my`](https://perldoc.pl/perlsub#Private-Variables-via-my()) for lexical scope, [`local`](https://perldoc.pl/perlsub#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29) or no declaration for dynamical scope.

There are two exceptions:

1. in ksh93, if a function is defined with the standard `function_name () { … }` syntax, then its local variables obey dynamic scoping. But if a function is defined with the ksh syntax `function function_name { … }` then its local variable obey lexical/static scoping, so they are not visible in other functions called by this.
2. the `zsh/private` autoloadable plugin in `zsh` provides with a `private` keyword/builtin which can be used to declare a variable with static scope.

ash, bash, pdksh and derivatives, bosh only have dynamic scoping.

Comment: Do all variables in the shell have a dynamic scope or does this only apply to variables declared with `local`?

Comment: @HaroldFischer All variables have dynamic scope. With a `typeset` or `declare` or `local` declaration, the scope is until the function returns. Without such a declaration, the scope is global.

Comment: IMHO, `If a variable is declared as local to a function, that scope remains until the function returns.` is not enough to explain what is dynamic scope verus lexical scope. The description alone is also applied to lexical scope.

Comment: @jinbeomhong No, with lexical scope, a variable from a function is not visible while this function calls another function. I've added a sentence to state this explicitly.

Comment: Does this also affect function calling builtins? Or does builtins have their own scope?

Comment: Also note that the module is (now?) called [`zsh/param/private`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparam_002fprivate-Module).

Answer (score 13):

In `function innerFunc()` the `var='new value'` wasn't declared as *local*, therefore it's available in visible scope (once the function has been called).

Conversely, in `function outerFunc()` the `local var='initial value'` was declared as *local*, therefore it's not available in the global scope (even if the function has been called).

Because `innerFunc()` was called as a child of `outerFunc()`, var is within the the local scope of `outerFunc()`.

`man 1 bash` may help clarify

> local [option] [name[=value] ...]
>
> For each argument, a local variable named name is created, and
>   assigned value.  The option can be any of the options accepted
>   by declare. When local is used within a function, it causes the
>   variable name to have a visible scope  restricted  to  that
>   function  and its children.  ...

The implied behavior that's expected in the description could be achieved by declaring `local var='new value` in `function innerFunc()`.

As others have stated, this is not a bug in the bash shell.  Everything's functioning as it should.

Comment: Your first statement contradicts what the user is seeing. Printing the value of `var` in the global scope, after calling `innerFunc` through `outFunc`, does not print `new value`.

Answer (score 11):

It isn't a bug, the call inside the context of the outerFunc uses that local copy of $var.  The "local" in outerFunc means the global isn't changed. If you call innerFunc outside of outerFunc, then there will be a change to the global $var, but not the outerFunc's local $var. If you added "local" to innerFunc, then outerFunc's $var wouldn't be changed - in essence, there'd be 3 of them:

- $global::var
- $outerFunc::var
- $innerFunc::var

to use Perl's namespace format, sort of.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a function to force local scope:

```
sh_local() {
  eval "$(set)" command eval '\"\$@\"'
}
```

Example:

```
x() {
  z='new value'
  printf 'function x, z = [%s]\n' "$z"
}
y() {
  z='initial value'
  printf 'function y before x, z = [%s]\n' "$z"
  sh_local x
  printf 'function y after x, z = [%s]\n' "$z"
}
printf 'global before y, z = [%s]\n' "$z"
y
printf 'global after y, z = [%s]\n' "$z"
```

Result:

```
global before y, z = []
function y before x, z = [initial value]
function x, z = [new value]
function y after x, z = [initial value]
global after y, z = [initial value]
```

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib/blob/b6b7c46/libstd.sh#L60-L62)

Comment: iiuc, in this code, `x` is running in a separate process (because of `command`), so its logging message is coming from that process, not from the process in which `y` is running.

Comment: @GregMinshall I dont really know, shell code is awful, so I dont use it anymore really

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. A local variable has dynamic scope: the variable is in scope until the function it has been declared in returns. Consequently, such variables are in scope for all functions called from this function.

If a function declares a new local variable, with the same name as another (local or global) variable, the new local variable will reside in a separate area of memory, and can hold values distinct from any others with the same name.

It doesn't matter where in the function a local declaration appears.

I modified the provided code a little as an example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function innerFunc() {
    echo "innerFunc:                   [var:${var}]"
}

function outerFunc() {
    local var='initial value'

    echo "outerFunc: before innerFunc: [var:${var}]"
    innerFunc
    echo "outerFunc: after  innerFunc: [var:${var}]"
}

echo "global:    before outerFunc: [var:${var}]"
outerFunc
echo "global:    after  outerFunc: [var:${var}]"
innerFunc
echo "global:    after  outerFunc: [var:${var}]"
```