# For loop stops after calling another function

Tags: bash, shell-script

Long story short I have a function.  Its called "months_and_days" down below. Its purpose is to create 24 logs per day and put them in a "year-month" directory.

I have a second function called "main" down below. Main create directories based on a simple for loop for 12 months. After the main function creates those directories it calls the "months_and_days" function to populate it with dummy log files.

For some reason, it only creates and populates the first months' directory "2018-01" and then stops...

I've never scripted in bash before so I'm not sure why after months_and_days finishes, it doesnt go back to the main function to complete it's loop.

Do I have to call the main function again and keep a global variable for the main loop?

Code below:

```
months=12
testDir=/home/name/bashScripts/testDir
fileToCopyPath=/opt/logs/192.168.217.129/2019-11/1-192.168.217.129-2019-11-24-13.log
currentMonth=0



function months_and_days () {
        declare -a daysArr=(31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31)
        for ((i=1; i<=${daysArr[$1]}; i++))
                do
                        for ((j=0; j<=23; j++ ))
                        do
                                if [ $j -le 9 ]
                                then
                                        tar -czvf $testDir/2018-$currentMonth/1-192-168-217-129-2018-$currentMonth-$i-0$j.tar.gz $fileToCopyPath
                                else
                                        tar -czvf $testDir/2018-$currentMonth/1-192-168-217-129-2018-$currentMonth-$i-$j.tar.gz $fileToCopyPath
                                fi
                        done
                done
}

function main () {
for ((i=1; i<=$months; i++))
do
        if [ $i -le 9 ]
        then
                mkdir $testDir/2018-0$i
                chmod 775 $testDir/2018-0$i
                currentMonth=0$i
                months_and_days "$i-1"

        else
                mkdir $testDir/2018-$i
                chmod 775 $testDir/2018-$i
                currentMonth=$i
                months_and_days "$i-1"
        fi
done
}

main
```

Comment: Perhaps because of the scope of `i`? See for example [Scope of Local Variables in Shell Functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282557/scope-of-local-variables-in-shell-functions)

Comment: @steeldriver thank you sir. You and Icarus were correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a global variable which is being altered in both the `main` and `months_and_days` functions. So after the first call to months_and_days the value of i is 32 (one more than the number of days in jan) so is greater than $months, so things stop.

Add a

```
local i
```

as the first line in months_and_days to fix it.

Comment: Atta be Icarus. Thank you for pointing out that I forgot the basic fundamentals of lexical scoping lol. Sometimes when learning new scripting or language I get so caught up in the syntax I forgot the basics lol

Comment: @noobcoderiam the point is that bash is **dynamically** scoped rather than **lexically** scoped. See comments in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551291/bash-experiment-to-save-and-restore-global-variable-context for a longer discussion where a professional compiler writer tells me I am wrong.